# prompt problem in VS editor or node js editor

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, leap-year

When i want to take user input in my code by taking command prompt vs code or node js editor says it is not defined. But as far i know we can take user input in JS by "prompt" .

example :-

```
function leapYear(year) {
    if ((year %2 == 0) && (year %100 != 0) || (year %400 == 0)) {
        console.log(year + " LeapYear");
    }
    else{
        console.log(year +" Not a LeapYear");
    }
  
}
const year = prompt('Enter a year:');


leapYear(year);
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: prompt is not defined

Comment: Do not use uppercase. It should be `prompt`, instead of `Prompt`.

Comment: If you're running in a browser then it is called `prompt` not `Prompt`, if you are running in Node.js then there's nothing equivalent to the web API `prompt` built-in and you'll need a library (or some manual dealing with the terminal). Your choice of editor is irrelevant.

Comment: @RezaSaadati i did't write Promt, i was write prompt and mistakenly  write here by uppercase. But i want to know how to take user input in JS.

Comment: @MohammadNajmulIslamRayhan your code works for me. See https://jsfiddle.net/5osmpqzk/ ... if that is not working for you, then you may have a browser issue.

Comment: @RezaSaadati — Given the mention of "node js editor" I'm pretty sure the issue is they aren't using a browser.

Comment: @RezaSaadati it's show a alert in this  jsfiddle.net/5osmpqzk site. but there i can't any output.

Comment: @Quentin i tried in both VS code editor and node js editor but in both place i face the same problem.

Comment: VS Code is an editor but doesn't run JS (except through external things) and Node.js isn't an editor, does run JS, but as I said earlier, doesn't implement Web APIs like `prompt`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get user input from the command line (so using node), use readline:

```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

let input = "";

rl.question("input here:\n", function (string) {
    input = string;
    console.log("input that was entered: " + input);
rl.close();
```

});

It's a bit more hassle than in other languages.

More here: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-get-user-input-from-command-line-with-javascript

There's a lot more to readline, so here's the official documentation:

https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

Comment: "It's a bit more hassle than in other languages." — Well, it is if you insist on doing it at such a low level instead of just finding a nice module on npm.

Comment: @Quentin feel free to post an answer using a nice module :-)

Comment: I'm not a fan of "just use my favourite library" answers, hence the suggestion to look for one I made in my first comment on the question.

Comment: @KatharineOsborne Thank you for your answer but i didn't get it. It's seems hard to get. Is there any easy way ?  And why not prompt ?

Comment: @MohammadNajmulIslamRayhan I'm not sure I understand. To use this answer you will need to run it at the command line. You will get the prompt there. Take a look at the screenshots at the first link in the answer.